# Python : Using a list in a function to print out results

Tags: python, list

My code is below:

```
def function(r):

    r = 6
    c = 10
    p = 0
    h = 0
    ht = 0.2
    o = 0.5
    l = 7
    a= [1.0,2.0,3.0]
    ol = o * l * a

    pp = zeros(0)
    aa = zeros(0)
    cc = zeros(0)
    pp = append(pp,p)
    aa = append(aa,a)
    cc = append(cc,c)

    while p >= 0 and h < 9:
        h = h + ht
        p = p + ol * ht
        result = r * cc * ht

    return result

ans = function(r)
print ans
```

Okay. I do not know for some reason, this program is giving me a TypeError. I do not know what it means. Please tell me what change I need to make to get rid of this error and get something to print out. The error is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f8ae1f1b5454> in <module>()
     25     return result
     26 
---> 27 ans = function(r)
     28 print ans

<ipython-input-23-f8ae1f1b5454> in function(r)
      9     l = 7
     10     a= [1.0,2.0,3.0]
---> 11     ol = o * l * a
     12 
     13     pp = zeros(0)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `o` and `l` are floats but `a` is a list.  What do you intend `ol = o * l * a` to do?

Comment: We can't help you because we have no idea what your function is actually supposed to do.

Comment: I want `ol` to take the assigned `o` and `l` value and multiply each other and with each of the value in the list `a`. The code itself is self-explanatory from there. I want to do the calculation `result = r * cc * ht` and return the value.

Comment: are you using numpy? ie numpy.zeros()? or is the function defined elsewhere?

Comment: In the vein of what @DanielRoseman said, It would be really helpful if you gave your variables less esoteric, for both us, anyone else reading your code, and your future self.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know what you are trying to say agconti. All my code is here. There is nothing elsewhere.

Comment: @will This is not my actual program. This is a simplified version, so that I can understand the actual program and the error in it.

Comment: @will  This looks like it is an old FORTRAN code converted to python.  In old numerical FORTRAN it was idomatic to use single or double letter variable names, especially for temporary variables.  Often, they represent the coefficient used in the mathematical representation of the function.  I'm not saying it was a good practice but that's what they did in the 70's and 80's.  It is entirely possible the OP simply converted the function and honestly has no idea what the variables actually mean so cannot improve their name.

Comment: Your 1st line of code is `def function(r):`,the second is `r = 6`.  You could write your function as `def function(r): return 42` as well.  That said, if you're in natural sciences you should know the distinction between a scalar and a vector.  To multiply vectors with scalars require either the use of  a specialized library (e.g., `numpy` that many other posters mentioned) or representing vectors with native (to python) data structures (i.e., lists), but now you have to use list comprehensions to do scalar vector multiplication, every time you need to compute such product. Every time. Always.

Comment: @SethMMorton I actually use fortran on a more or less daily basis, even as dated as 66. And yes, the variables are obviously those of an equation, but it's still infinitely more clear to give them proper names.

Comment: @will Agreed.  My point is that the OP probably doesn't know what each variable is for (since as you are probably aware old FORTRAN writers also did *not* like to comment their code), so they cannot give them proper names.

Comment: @SethMMorton [*plenty* of comments in the ones i use...](http://www.tampa.phys.ucl.ac.uk/rmat/oldest/swmol3.f)

Comment: @will  Haha.. looks like you are one of the lucky ones!

Comment: @SethMMorton I have some truely awful ones somewhere, things like 6 or 7 nested for loops with al lthe variables caleld things like iijkji

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to do is multiply `o` and `l` across `a`.  There are two ways you can do that:

1. List comprehension

This explicitly iterates through the list and modifies each value, creating a new list object.

```
ol = [o*l*x for x in a]
```

2. `map(func, interable)`

This method implicitly does the same thing as the comprehension; applies `func` to every entry of `iterable`. In this example I've used a lambda function as `func`, but you could go and define a whole function if you'd like

```
ol = map(lambda x: o*l*x, a)
```

Most folks prefer comprehensions because they're more clear and usually fast. Either of these two methods should solve your `TypeError`, but your code will not do what you want.

You assign the return of `append(pp,p)` to the list `pp`.  This will make `pp` equal to `None` since thats what hte function returns.  `append()` is intended to mutate lists, so you should use  `pp.append(p)` to attach `p` to the end of `pp`

Comment: List comprehension does not work. It is giving me the same error, but now at `p = p + ol * ht`

Comment: I also changed `append(pp,p)` to `pp.append(p)`, but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: You need to do one of these two methods every time you try to multiple a single object with an iterable

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. I am not good at this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `numpy`, the best solution is to convert `a` into a numpy array.  The rest of your code will work as-is.

```
a= array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
ol = o * l * a  # Vectorized because numpy
```

This assumes you have done `from numpy import array` before the function call.